# Confusion about MIMO (spatial multiplexing) in Rayleigh fading

Tags: wireless

A Rayleigh fading channel is supposed to be constituting a rich scattering environment thus suitable for spatial multiplexing, yet Rayleigh fading BER  performance is very bad when compared to an AWGN channel, so how can a high throughput be achieved with MIMO in a Rayleigh fading channel? isn't there a controversy here?

Comment: No. MIMO ensures typically only one path is in a deep fade at any one time. Don't forget the effect of OFDM as well, which MIMO is typically only used with, which your question ignoers.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing spatial diversity with spatial multiplexing? Regarding OFDM suppose we have a flat fading condition where all subcarriers encounter the same deep fading, this could be a valid case

Comment: 'thus suitable for spatial multiplexing' - I didn't call you out on this. Spatial multiplexing **requires** multipath, flat Rayleigh fading is not sufficient. If you have multipath, then OFDM is the mod type to use. A 'rich' scattering environment is not a sufficient specification to go into the detail of what you want to discuss.

Comment: OFDM is a divide and conquer strategy which allow us to deal with each subcarrier separately and thus makes it much more suitable for dealing with a multiple antenna channel matrix , however multipath is what is required in order to distinguish between the different streams, multipath leads to fading which could be frequency selective or flat, so OFDM is only a convenient tool